# color of the titles of questions

Tags: feature-request

The color of the title of a non-visited question on the main site is blue, and that of an already visited question is dark-blue.

I believe, visually it would be more helpful if the color of an already visited question is less dark with respect to a non-visited question or is completely different (like on mathoverflow, math.SE,  tex, academia, and this meta!).

Answer (score 4):

This site is in beta and thus uses the standard theme for beta sites. A change would thus have to be made to the general beta-theme.

Indeed your proposal came up on the network-wide meta

[Beta theme visited link color seems "wrong" to me](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143809/beta-theme-visited-link-color-seems-wrong-to-me)

There it transpired that early this was different. It thus seems quite unlikely to me this will be changed back. I am sorry I cannot say anything more supportive;  in any case this is outside the control of per-site moderators (especially for the beta-theme).